# Play video using Childbrowser plugin in landscape, when my App is entirely in portrait mode

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can change the orientation to play a video in landscape mode through childbrowser plugin when my app is only in portrait mode? Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

My solution may gives you the answer to your problem.

Add these plugins and check it.

http://github.com/bubblefoundry/CDVVideo

http://moduscreate.com/opening-all-urls-with-phonegaps-childbrowser-plugin/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.